# Send a message to multiple devices with Firebase http v1 api

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to send a message to multiple devices with new Firebase http v1 API?

Before I use the legacy http protocol, so I just send messages to users with their registration tokens:

```
{
  "to": [reg_token_1, reg_token_2, ...,],
  "priority": "high",
  "data": {
    "title": "Hello!",
    "message": "Hello everyone"
  }
}
```

Is there any way to send message to multiple registration tokens if using new http v1 api?

Comment: Maybe one has to create a [device group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group)?

Answer (score -1):

You can use “channels” for this (named topics).

Comment: This is more a workarond, as you need to add topic management (i.e. topic subcribtion). Is there is a way to target sepcific registration tokens in one REST post?